# gtk changes all ss to ß gtk themes not saved on restart

Tags: gtk, locale

I am using Kubuntu 14.04 and have the following problem:

All GTK apps (thunderbird, Polly, Gimp and so on are changing all `ss` to `ß`)
locale is de_DE this happens in all Menus lists and so on.

Is there a way to change the default behavior?